# Save OWL ontology imports closure offline

Tags: owl, protege

How can I use standard existing tools, like Protege or the OWL API, to save the "imports closure" of an OWL ontology to file?

The default saving mechanism seems to permit dependencies on web resources via import statements. This means that ontologies saved this way cannot be completely opened when the host is not connected to the internet.

Note that I am not asking how to save an inferred ontology.

Comment: *Refactor > Merge ontologies* and *File > Gather ontologies* are useful sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is to navigate the imports closure and save each ontology to a file. Saving all files in one folder, an AutoIRIMapper can be pointed at the folder and used in follow up loading of the root ontology - it will prefer the local files to the remote links.